# PyPI: ics - can't generate calender (string = string.replace("\\", "\\\\") AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace')

Tags: python, icalendar, traceback

My code is this:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from ics import Calendar, Event
for i in range(1, 365+1):
    c = Calendar()
    e = Event()
    e.name = i
    startdate = pd.Timestamp("08/01/2023")
    date = str(startdate + pd.DateOffset(days=i-1))
    print(str(i) + ": " + date)
    e.begin = date
    e.end = date
    c.events.add(e)

with open('my.ics', 'w') as my_file:
    my_file.write(c.serialize())
```

And it returns this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\******\dev\66795\main.py", line 15, in <module>
    my_file.write(c.serialize())
  File "C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\ics\component.py", line 72, in serialize
    output(self, container)
  File "C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\ics\serializers\icalendar_serializer.py", line 27, in serialize_event
    container.append(event.serialize())
  File "C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\ics\component.py", line 72, in serialize
    output(self, container)
  File "C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\ics\serializers\event_serializer.py", line 51, in serialize_summary
    container.append(ContentLine("SUMMARY", value=escape_string(event.name)))
  File "C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\ics\utils.py", line 218, in escape_string
    string = string.replace("\\", "\\\\")
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

I want a calender that says every day the number. Like this:
07.31: 001
08.01: 002
08.02: 003
...

Comment: `e.name = i` is the problem. The name should be a string.

Comment: what is `pd` ?  this is not defined....

Comment: @D.L `pd` is defined in the line `import pandas as pd`.